# spark streaming - waiting for a dead executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming, spark-operator

I have a spark streaming application running inside a k8s cluster (using spark-operator).

I have 1 executor, reading batches every 5s from a Kinesis stream.
The Kinesis stream has 12 shards, and the executor creates 1 receiver per shard. I gave it 24 cores, so it should be more than enough to handle it.

For some unknown reason, sometimes the executor crashes. I suspect it is due to memory going over the k8s pod memory limit, which would cause k8s to kill the pod. But I have not been able to prove this theory yet.

[image]

After the executor crashes, a new one is created.

However, the "work" stops. The new executor is not doing anything.

I investigated a bit:

- Looking at the logs of the pod - I saw that it did execute a few tasks successfully after it was created, and then it stopped because it did not get any more tasks.
- Looking in Spark Web UI - I see that there is 1 “running batch” that is not finishing.

[image]
[image]

I found some docs that say there can always be only 1 active batch at a time. So this is why the work stopped - it is waiting for this batch to finish.

Digging a bit deeper in the UI, I found this page that shows details about the tasks.

[image]

So executor 2 finished doing all the tasks it was assigned.
There are 12 tasks that were assigned to executor 1 which are still waiting to finish, but executor 1 is dead.

Why does this happen? Why does Spark not know that executor 1 is dead and never going to finish it's assigned tasks? I would expect Spark to reassign these tasks to executor 2.

Comment: Could you clarify how you start/stop k8s pods? Are they k8s Jobs/CronJobs? And do they stop on purpose if they don't get any more tasks? I mean, are you seeing unexpected k8s pod behavior?

Comment: @mozello I am running `kubectl apply -f conf.yaml` of a `SparkApplication`. It is a CRD of `spark-operator`. I have `spark-operator` on the k8s cluster that is responsible to create the actual pods from the `SparkApplication`.

I don't know why the pod stops sometimes. I think it crashes, but I still haven't figured out why. But regardless of the reason - when an executor pod crashes, a new one is created, and I don't understand why Spark does not "know" that it should use this new pod from now on. It seems to still be waiting for an answer from the "dead" executor.

Comment: Also - it's not because "there are no more tasks". There are definitely many more tasks to run. They are all waiting for the current "running batch" to finish.

Comment: we are also faing similar issue when executors killed for some reason, it is not being properly removed and restarted. Have you found anything useful on this ?